# valueChanges attempt throws error of object being null (reactive forms)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Angular 4 question.

I am trying to decipher some parts of reactive forms in angular, more specifically related to the forms being reactive, responding to user action.

I want to attempt an action on a user input, namely to select from a list of a suggestions.

So in the constructor I have the formBuilder and the service that helps me build the values from which I pick the one for my input field.

Problem is, when I want to play around with valueChanges, to capture the value I entered and do something with it, I get a 'object is possibly null' error even though I took some precautions against the object being null.

Such as: extra conditions and before that, actually defining the myForm inside initForm (so for sure it can't be null).

Any quick pointers please and thanks!

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private myService: MyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm(this.formBuilder);
  }


 private initForm(formBuilder: FormBuilder): void {
    this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      input1: ['', Validators.minLength(3)],
      input2: [{value: '', disabled: true}]
     });

    if (this.myForm) {
      if (this.myForm.get('input1')) {
        this.myForm.get('input1').valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Denys, do you mean leaving it like this: `input1: [{value: ''}],` or `input1: [{value: '', disabled: false}],` - I tried both these variants but I still get that null issue. Thank you

Comment: does it go inside this.myform? Can you console.log your input there?

Comment: this goes inside the formBuilder.group definition just like in my above code where I first add the form controls to the form by their name (in the html I have equivalent formControlName="input1" and so on). This form group definition is inside the initForm method, and AFTER the definition of the form group (as seen from my code), I reference the form group, so it's suprising that it's null (isn't it?)

Comment: Denys, thanks for the idea. Now I am even more suprised. So console.log(this.myForm); has the expected value and on the next line
  this.myForm.get('input1').valueChange throws object may be null

Comment: all expected 3? input1,input2 and?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant 3 steps, not 3 values. I have 3 steps in my method: 1. define form group, 2. log form to console and 3. attempt to apply value changed on my form

Comment: Ok. Why do you use this. on your form? Do you have it declared somewhere at the top?

Comment: Yes it's a class property  `myForm: FormGroup;`

Comment: Just noticed the problem doesn't appear until I add `.valueChanges` to this expression `this.myForm.get('input1')` but still unsure how to fix it

Comment: this.myForm.get('input1')!.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value));

Comment: Thank you very much Denys did you mean ? or !  - never seen the ! syntax before. Unfortunately not working yet with either ? or !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169714/discussion-between-denys-fiialko-and-annepic).

Comment: How about adding this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value));

Comment: I've posted the answer for those who will stumble onto this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (this.myForm) {
      if (this.myForm.get('input1')) {
       const variable = this.myForm.get('input1'); // create a variable 
        variable!.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value)); // use Non-null assertion operator(used in Typescript 2)
        }
    }
```

Because compiler cannot tell as a fact, that that variable is null, we need to use a non-null assertion operator.assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined.

Comment: Million thanks Denys. For some reason despite all previous checks i had to add // tslint:disable-next-line:no-non-null-assertion before my variable!.... line. tslint bug I guess? Works great now.

Comment: it's not a bug and it doesn't affect your program. A rule from the tslint states: "Using non-null assertion cancels the benefits of the strict null checking mode." They just try to be as robust as possible

Comment: Apparently using subscribe this way is deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should do this

```
let input1 = this.myForm.get('input1');
if (input1 != null) {
    input1.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}
```

Comment: Amaya thank you but unfortunately I get the same issue even with this additional check

Comment: This doesn't make any difference,both statements are equal. if (this.myForm.get('input1') != null) is identical to if (this.myForm.get('input1'))